# Google Plus sharing using shareDialog not working

Tags: ios, google-plus, sharing

In my iOS app I have integrated google plus sdk, and GooglePlus Sign In is one of the login options.

Since sharing should work without google sign in into the app, so I used following code

```
    id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
[GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;

    [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Title name" description:@"description" thumbnailURL:imageUrl];

    [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:deepLinkId];

    [shareBuilder open];
```

On starting share, google plus opens in safari browser asks login if there is no login session. And just opens google plus timeline page.
Sharing preview page and sharing action is not coming.

Any idea on what may be wrong?

Comment: Same issue here, do you have a solution for it?